# How to I get scatter plot to have different colour for each value that I am plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used read.xlsx to get a data from excel. What I want to do with the data is that I want to plot a scatterplot with latitude as my y-axis and longitude as my x-axis. I want to have a count label such that it shows the scale of my value and with the lower value colored blue and the highest value being red. How do I do this?  Currently this is my data.

```
> getdata

     No.          latitude                longitude                   Value
1   300           22.23418                80.71113                     0.696
2   400           1.15923                 115.82203                    0.686
3   450           37.60778                96.09940                     0.459
4   900           27.65468                127.00649                    0.718
5   940           33.61151                166.54130                    0.837
```

And this is what I have for the scatterplot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = getdata, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude)) +
  scale_color_continuous(getdata, low = "blue", high = "red")
```

However all I get is black points. Why is that so and how do I fix this? I think it is because the 'value' part from the data was left out in the `ggplot()`.

Sorry I'm new to this but thank you for any help.

Comment: ggplot has pretty detailed online docs that also link to several good tutorials. I'd recommend starting there. You've given an argument `getdata` to `scale_color_continuous`, but as far as I can tell that argument doesn't actually go anywhere. You also haven't told your plot what the color should be associated with—that needs to happen inside `aes`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```r
getdata <- data.frame(
    latitude=c(22.23418, 1.15923, 37.60778, 27.65468, 33.61151), 
    longitude=c(80.71113, 115.82203, 96.09940, 127.00649, 166.54130),
    Value=c(0.696, 0.686, 0.459, 0.718, 0.837))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=getdata, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, color=Value))+
        geom_point()+
        scale_color_continuous( low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>